# Get the non-ModifierKey c#

Tags: c#, ctrl

I try to get the non-ModifierKeys from the pressKey event.
To get the ModifierKey i use:

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
```

But how do i get the non-ModifierKeys?
Not just a specific key. But all combination a-z 0-9.

I want to know if `CTRL`+A or `CTRL`+5 or `CTRL`+B is pressed or any combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to identify whether a the keypress was a letter or a digit you could do something like

```
  private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {                  
                //do A
            }
            else
            {
                //do B
            }
        }
```

But if you want which key was pressed, you could handle the KeyDown event whose KeyEventArgs will have which key was pressed.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Keys keyPressed = e.KeyCode;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you.
When i move the code to KeyDown it works.
Always been using Keypess before.In this case that was not a good idea.
ofcourse it will pick up just CTRL because its the first key to be pressed. But if i use KeyDown i get the last key how was down. Witch will be the non-ModifierKey.

Answer (score 1):

`Control` does not provide a property that lists all the pressed keys. You need to pick it up in a event, like [`KeyPress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: the code are in the KeyPress even.
if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)